# Javascript/PHP - Get last post ID from livechat system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently upgrading my livechat system to use the append function with JavaScript.

And in order to get it to work I will need to get the latest chat date or ID somehow.

So I can then do a query like:

```
SELECT date, message, name FROM chat WHERE id > $lastPostId";
```

This will then allow me to append all the latest messages instead of updating all of the HTML everytime there is a new message

**So basically, my chat right now works like this:**

Every second it checks for my PHP file, loadchat.php.

Loadchat.php will get every single message from the database

It then replaces all current data in my div: #chatbox by using .html() function.

And I want to change it to the append function in jquery allowing it to run a lot smoother

Because it only needs to read everything the first time and then append

**So my question is, how do I get the last post ID?**

Comment: how about you add `id` to the fields you select? (the clean way would be to use timestamps, by the way - ids should **not** be asumed to be in order)

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

Add one more field in your database called timestamp. When you update the chat you can store the value of last timestamp in session.Now each time fetching a new chat just send that timestamp to loadchat.php and query the db to fetch rows where timestamp > stored_timestamp.

Case 2:

You can take a flag in db like is_read. When you insert the new chat the default value of is_read will be 0. When you fetch the data just update the flag i.e is_read = 1. Now in your query you just have to check for the flag.

```
where is_read = 0.
```

It will fetch all the unread messages and will do the job.

Hope it will help!!